# How to pass value to popover from renderer

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have defined and created popover using "react-bootstrap".

```
import { Popover, ButtonToolbar, OverlayTrigger, Button } from "react-bootstrap";
```

and

```
const popoverClick = (
    <Popover id="popover-trigger-click" title="Popover bottom">
        <strong>TODO: </strong> Plan Info...
    </Popover>
);
```

and calling it from renderer.

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={popoverClick}>
    <a href="#"> Plan</a>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

It works with static data "TODO: Plan Info..." but I was wondering if I want to display my data on popover how do I pass the value?

P.S. - New to ReactJs :)

Thanks,
Faizan

Answer (score 2):

`overlay` value can be component. you can pass the props using components.

**PopoverComponent:**

```
const PopoverComponent = ({myData})=>{

    return (<Popover id="popover-trigger-click" title="Popover bottom">
        <strong>{myData}</strong> Plan Info...
    </Popover>)
}
```

**OverlayTrigger:**

```
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={<PopoverComponent myData={'sayHello'} />}>
    <a href="#"> Plan</a>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Comment: Many Thanks :) Works like a charm

Comment: One Follow-up Qns. What about the position of popover on UI, placement="left" or "bottom" does not seem to work anymore and popup is not opening next to the button.

Comment: Please check docs for the same.Either css are getting overwritten or not applied.

Comment: How do I write it if I want to dynamically populate the contents of popover with data received from ajax request?